# Compilation warnings in driver after including ksmedia.h

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, kmdf

I'm developing a driver bases on Microsoft's [Toaster KMDF filter driver example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/toaster/toastDrv/kmdf/filter/generic). I've included the headers `windef.h`, `ks.h`, `ksmedia.h`, and now I'm seeing the following warnings:

Warning #1:

> `\\...\ksmedia.h(732): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to 'STATIC_KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_WAV'`

Line 732 of ksmedia.h reads:

```
#if !defined( STATIC_KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_WAVEFORMATEX )
```

Warning #2:

> `\\...\ksmedia.h(7795): warning RC4067: unexpected characters following '#endif' directive; newline expected`

Line 7795 of ksmedia.h reads:

```
#endif _AUDIO_CURVE_TYPE_
```

That happens even though I have another project (not KMDF) which includes the header files, and doesn't display the warnings.

Can you help me understand the reason for this? Can I do something to remove the warnings?

Comment: Could you include lines 732 and 7795 of `ksmedia.h`?

Comment: Maybe this header is not compatible with current environment/ddk.

Comment: @DevSolar https://imgur.com/a/XPAvD

Comment: why you compile c++ code with *rc* compiler ?

Comment: @Paul: Including relevant codes and messages *in the question itself* and *as text* is much preferred over external image links (or included images).

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934221) seconding comment by @RbMm -- compiling "normal" source with the resource compiler.

Comment: look like you add `#include <ksmedia.h>` to `filter.rc` file - remove this include. also from example `#include <windows.h>
#include <filter.h>
#include <ntverp.h>` - remove too. it absolute not need in *rc* file. if need - include `#include "winres.h"` only

Comment: @RbMm here are my includes (in .h file): https://i.imgur.com/VcnCiDA.png

Comment: no, show your rc file

Comment: I didn't change it: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/general/toaster/toastDrv/kmdf/filter/generic/filter.rc

Comment: not believe. you include <ksmedia.h> direct or indirect (via another include) to rc file. and this error exactly when you compile your rc

Comment: Looks like I found out the cause. `#include <filter.h>` in .rc file includes `filter.h` in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your error, i can say that you direct or indirect (via another include) add line:

```
#include <ksmedia.h>
```

in *rc* file. when RC (Resource Compiler) process `ksmedia.h` he give exactly this warnings and errors. because `ksmedia.h` not designed to be processed by *RC* compiler. also include `windows.h` and `filter.h` to rc (as in example) also error by sense. if need some definitions/macros for *RC* - include `winres.h` only